# JavaScript upcall to JavaFX FXML

Tags: javafx-2, fxml

I am using FXML WebView in SampleController.java to display web contents. Now problem is how to call java function from javascript in html file or when click on webview web page should execute javascript and call code in Bridge() to execute. There are examples for JavaFX WebView but could not find any example for FXML WebView.

```
    public class SampleController implements Initializable {

    @FXML Button write, read;
    @FXML ToolBar toolbar;
    @FXML WebView webview;
    WebEngine webEngine;
    JSObject window;

    @FXML
    private void setText(MouseEvent e){
        webEngine.executeScript("writeText()");
    }
    @FXML
    private void getText(MouseEvent e){
        String str = (String) webEngine.executeScript("readText()");
        System.out.println(str);
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        webEngine = webview.getEngine();
        webEngine.load(getClass().getResource("test.html").toString());

     webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Worker.State>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends State> ov, State t, State t1) {
        if (t1 == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
            window = (JSObject) webEngine.executeScript("window");
            window.setMember("app", new Bridge());

        }
    }
});     
    }    
}

   // code for javaScript call

    public class Bridge {   
    public void exit() {
        Platform.exit();
    }

    public void display(String str){
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}

// Here is HTML with with javaScript
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script>
            function writeText(){
                document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = "New text!";
            }
            function readText(){
                var str = document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML;
                return str;
            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="div1">Urdu Books<img src="book.png" alt="book"></div>
        <div id="div2">Here is a text for you!</div>
        <div id="div3"></div>
        <p>Click <a href="#" onclick="java.exit()">here </a>to exit the application
        <p>Click <a href="#" onclick="java.display('This is value')"> Display </a> a value
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Whe doing this `window.setMember("app", new Bridge());` you basically tell the JS engine to set a new Bridge object as the `app` member of your window object.

Now in your javascript code you can just call your bridge methods such as `window.app.exit()` or more simply `app.exit()` as `window` is the global object.